# In JAVA, JButton, Button displayed only when cursor is on the button and works even on clicking anywhere in contentPane

Tags: java, swing, click, jframe, jbutton

I am a beginner into Java and OOPS in general. Am studyin Head First Java to start, and studying GUI and Swing concepts in it. 
The below code is just for understanding purposes.

On running the code, The frame window is displayed with Button, and when I expand it I can see Radio Button too.

Issues-

1. *Button works till the window size is not more than the button size . As soon as I increase the window size even slightly more than button's dimensions, then the button is displayed only when cursor is on it.*

I am changing window size using mouse.

1. *Also even if I set Frame size to be more than button. say frame.setSize(800,800); then the button covers whole contentPane. and still behaves same way on resizing.*
2. *And the button responds to clicking on mouse, irrespective of where I click in the contentPane. It should respond only when i click directly on the button.*

Please inform me why it is behaving this way.

And if possible,corrections in code or additions to correct this.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Test1 implements ActionListener {

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
JButton button = new JButton("Button!");
JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton("VideoKilledTheRadioStar!",true);
int j=0;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test1 t = new Test1();
    t.method1();

}
public void method1()
{

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
button.setSize(100,100);
button.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
frame.add(button);
frame.setSize(100,100);
frame.setVisible(true);
button.addActionListener(this);
frame.getContentPane().add(radio);
radio.addActionListener(this);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{j++;
button.setText("clicked .. " + j);

    if(button.getBackground()==Color.ORANGE)
    button.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    else
        button.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
}

}
```

P.S I did not know which segment of code is important or more relevant to this question, so I have put complete code.

Comment: Please do spare a moment to read about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), even if you rectify the thingy as explained in answers, still the code is not safe with respect to the Swing's point of view, that's why the importance of the link.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding the `JButton` `button` and the `JRadioButton` both in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` location so only one is being displayed. Components at this location will be sized in the X and Y axis.

The `JButton` only displays when the cursor is over it due to the fact that it has its own `MouseListener` used for painting.

Also, the statements

```
frame.add(myComponent);
```

and

```
frame.getContentPane().add(myComponent);
```

both add the component to the frame's `ContentPane` & are equivalent but the first is chosen for convenience.

Note that components cannot co-exist in the same position in a `BorderLayout`. You could place the `button` at the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` position (& add directly to the frame):

```
frame.add(radio, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

`BorderLayout` disregards any preferred sizes for components so you would have to use a different layout manager such as `BoxLayout` to maintain a fixed size `JButton`.

See more about [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: yes! that solved the button disappearing problem, Thanks a lot!!

I think whatever function in JVM would display it on-screen would be confused which component, button or radio button to display. 

If JButton has its own MouseListener, does that mean that I should not have added my own ActionListener or should have coded it some other way. 

Also the JButton still changes its size as the window changes size.

Comment: No, `ActionListener` & `MouseListener` do 2 completely different tasks. You still need the former to perform tasks when an `ActionEvent` occurs.

Comment: okay, so then when I further study about actionListener and event listeners,  in general. Then I think I will be able to clear this doubt.  I will get back when I read more, thank you!

Comment: @Reimeus Does `frame.add(myComponent)`and `frame.getContentPane().add(myComponent)` may solve same purpose if there are many  panes or layered?

Comment: No, that will produce the same result. You need to look at using a different layout manager. Have a look at some of these [BoxLayout examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to add the `JButton` button and `JRadioButton` objects in the default layout(`BorderLayout`) of the `JFrame`.

Whenevery you add a component to JFrame having `BorderLayout` the components goes in the Middle Section and `BorderLayout` center section has tendency to occupy the complete space, so to position elements properly you will need to specify the location as well as set the PreferredSize of the component.

```
frame.add(radio, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
component.setPreferredSize(Dimension);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, okay so I should position my objects in different sections then. 

Is there a way to limit the size of the button, irrespective of the size of the window.

Comment: This should help you understand how to use BorderLayout http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html